# Finding the equation of the path of sled

Tags: calculus

Suppose you are going to go out sledding and you are dragging your sled behind you
with a 1 metre long rope. Further suppose that you are standing at the origin with
your sled lying on the positive x-axis and that you start walking along the positive
y-axis. As you walk along the y-axis, the sled drags along the path drawn below where
the rope is always tangent to the path. Find the equation of the function that gives
the path of the sled.

Image:

[image]

Can someone give me some tips on this problem? I'm stuck on how I would actually start this. Just tips will be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let the position of the sled at time $t$ be $(x(t),y(t))$.  Your position is $(0,t)$.  We know you are one meter from the sled, so $x(t)^2+(1-y(t))^2=1$  The sled is pulled toward you, so $\frac {dy(t)}{dx(t)}=\frac {t-y(t)}{x(t)}$

Comment: Sorry I'm still working on this problem. I've isolated the value of y(t) but I'm not sure what I should do once I've substituted into the dy(t)/dx(t) equation.

Comment: Actually, if you just want the curve, you get $x^2+y^2-2y=0$, which  you can write as $x=\sqrt {y^2-2y}$ or you can solve with the quadratic equation.  That doesn't tell you when the sled is at each point, but it does give the path of the sled.  If you want the time for each point, you can implicitly differentiate this to get $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and plug that into the second equation.  It turns out you get $x^2$, which you can eliminate with the first equation, giving a quadratic equation in $y,t$